# Network connections immediately closed when connecting to home server from home

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, vnc

My SSH and VNC connections freeze a few seconds after they get established when I connect to my home Linux computers from home using their external IP addresses. Everything works fine when I connect to them from an outside computer or from home using their local IP addresses. The Linux computers are connected to a Zyxel DSL router (*o2 HomeBox 6441*) which also does the port-forwarding.

I was thinking that I might encounter a [NAT loopback or hairpinning problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) explained [here](https://superuser.com/a/454471/549571), [here](https://serverfault.com/q/55611/330169) and [here](https://superuser.com/q/860615/549571).

However, what surprises me is that the connections gets established and I can even type a few characters or receive half of a VNC screen.
Another surprise is that I can establish an SSH connection if I connect to another external computer and SSH back home form there. But if I enable X11 forwarding, the problem is back and the connection freezes.

I don't see any difference in the `ssh -vvv` output between the local and failing external connection.

What could be the problem?